# Gamblers Ruin with multiple coins tossed at the same time

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability, independence

I'm quite ashamed to be stuck with a Gambler's Ruin problem, I guess I'm missing some basic statistical intuition here:

Three fair coins tossed. Heads gets +1, tails -1, pay-offs are added and net pay-off added to equity. The 3 tosses are repeated 1000 times. Initial equity is 10 $ . What is the probability of total ruin (within +/- 0.05 error)?

I simulated the problem as 3 iid coin tosses in one round which is then repeated, the same as it would be with a repeated one coin toss. My simulated probability of ruin converges to ca. 83%, while 100% would be the correct answer.
The only hint I have is 'Flipping a coin in succession is different from flipping three concurrently from markov lens'. Could someone help me and explain?

Thanks!!

Tobi

```
import numpy as np

class GamblersRuin(object):
    """
    Three fair coins tossed. Heads gets +1, tails -1, pay-offs are added and net pay-off 
    added to equity.
    The 3 tosses are repeated 1000 times. Initial equity is 10 dollars
    p: probability that gambler is successful/ wins at each round.
    i: gambler's initial amount of money/reserves
    """

def __init__(self, p, init_bal):
    self.p = p
    self.init_bal = init_bal
    self.bal = init_bal
    self.q = 1 - self.p
    self.realizations = np.array(self.init_bal)
    self.simulation_results = []

def coin_toss(self):
    """
    One coin flip with payoff (1, -1) with probability (p,q)
    """
    outcome = np.random.uniform(0, 1)

    if outcome < self.p:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = -1

    return result

def play_one_round(self):
    """
    Three coin tosses in one round round
    """
    result_round = 0
    for i in range(0,3):
        result_round += self.coin_toss()
    return result_round

def gamble(self, no_rounds):
    """
    One round is played until ruin or no_rounds times
    """
    self.realizations = np.array(self.init_bal)
    self.bal = self.init_bal

    round = 1
    while round < no_rounds:
        round_result = self.play_one_round()
        if (self.bal + round_result) >= 0:
            self.bal += round_result
        else:
            break
        self.realizations = np.append(self.realizations, self.bal)
        round += 1

def simulate(self, no_simulations, no_rounds):
    # Gamble multiple times and store realization paths
    self.simulation_results = []

    for game in range(1,no_simulations+1):
        self.gamble(no_rounds=no_rounds)
        self.simulation_results.append(self.realizations)
```

Comment: where does it say it is 100%? Surely, it's < 1 if not rounded. Could you share your source?

Comment: @gunes https://twitter.com/mikeharrisNY/status/1315426197413621760. It converges to 100%. Also https://twitter.com/mikeharrisNY/status/1315721008985374723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Monte Carlo method

DyedPurple already showed that your simulation is not wrong and you should get a probability of ~0.84 for a run length of 1000. It is only when the run length goes towards infinity that you are almost certain to get gambler's ruin (If you have a stopping rule for some upper boundary, as in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401480), then you can escape the gambler's ruin with some non-zero probability).

In this answer, I show how you can compute it exactly instead of simulating it with a Monte Carlo method. (and there is also an approximate analytic solution by comparing the situation with Brownian motion).

#### Computation as a Markov chain

The problem is similar to this question [Amoeba Interview Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/) or this question [The Frog Problem (puzzle in YouTube video)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427165)

The probabilities, $P_k(x)$, to have $x$ money after $k$ tosses can be expressed in terms of the probabilities for earlier tosses:

$$P_k(x) = \frac{1}{8} P_{k-1}(x-3) + \frac{3}{8} P_{k-1}(x-1) + \frac{3}{8} P_{k-1}(x+1) + \frac{1}{8} P_{k-1}(x+3)$$

With this formula, you can already compute the result for 1000 steps (see the R-code and the image below).

#### Comparison with a diffusion process

You can also model the amount of money as *approximately* a one-dimensional diffusion process or a Brownian motion (the solution is given in 1916 by Smoluchowski, more on that in the answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/401539).

The amount of money $M_k$ in step $k$ changes relatively to the amount in the previous step $M_{k-1}$ by the addition of a random variable

$$M_k = M_{k-1} + \epsilon_k$$

In this case the random variable $\epsilon_k$ is a scaled and shifted binomial distributed variable that takes values $-3$, $-1$, $1$, $3$, with probabilities $1/8$, $3/8$, $3/8$, $1/8$. This variable has a variance equal to 3.

We can relate this to a diffusion process or Brownian motion where the diffusivity is equal to the variance of the variable $\epsilon$.

The time to reach a certain point, the first hitting time, follows an [inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution). Or since there is no drift it is a Levy Distribution. Then the hitting time is distributed according to a Levy distribution with parameters $m=0$ and $s = (10/\sqrt{3})^2$. We can use the cumulative distribution function to model the fraction of cases that have hit the point of zero money after 1000 steps.

#### Example

The graph and code below demonstrate the computation with the Markov chain and the estimation with the Levy distribution.

[image: computation and estimate]

```r
kmax <- 3000

### a kmax times 3kmax matrix for the 
### probability to be with profit x in step k
###
### note: in R code the index starts with 1, and this relates to 0 money
###
Pxk <- matrix(rep(0,3*kmax^2),3*kmax)

Pxk[11,1] = 1 ### start with x=10 money in step k=1

### compute each coin toss
for (i in 2:kmax) {
  ### compute the cases when money is 5 or larger
  for(j in 4:(3*kmax-5)) {
    Pxk[j,i] <- (1/8)*Pxk[j-3,i-1] + (3/8)*Pxk[j-1,i-1] + (3/8)*Pxk[j+1,i-1] + (1/8)*Pxk[j+3,i-1]
  }
  ### compute the special cases when money is 0,1,2 or 3 or smaller
  Pxk[1,i] <- Pxk[1,i-1] +  (4/8)*Pxk[2,i-1] + (1/8)*Pxk[3,i-1] + (1/8)*Pxk[4,i-1]
  Pxk[2,i] <- (3/8)*Pxk[3,i-1] + (1/8)*Pxk[5,i-1]
  Pxk[3,i] <- (3/8)*Pxk[2,i-1] + (3/8)*Pxk[4,i-1] + (1/8)*Pxk[6,i-1]
  Pxk[4,i] <- (3/8)*Pxk[3,i-1] + (3/8)*Pxk[5,i-1] + (1/8)*Pxk[7,i-1]
}

### plot the simulation
plot(Pxk[1,], type = "l",
     ylab = expression(P[ruin]), xlab = "number of tosses", ylim = c(0,1))

### add a curve based on the Levy distribution
n <- c(1:3000)
dist <- 10
sigma <- 2 * 1/8 * 3^2 + 2 * 3/8 * 1^2 ### variance of steps relates to diffusion rate
lines(n,rmutil::plevy(n, m = 0, s = dist^2/sigma), col= 2)

### highlight the point for 1000 tosses
points(1000,Pxk[1,1000], pch = 21, col = 1, bg = 0)
text(1000,Pxk[1,1000], expression(P %~~% 0.85), pos = 1, cex = 0.7)

legend(1000,0.4, c("exact computation","Levy distribution (diffusion model)"), 
       col = c(1,2), lty = 1, cex = 0.7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct. I wrote the following simulation (Python 3) and got the same result as you (i.e. that the probability of ruin is ~0.84).

```
import random

def flip_3_coins():
    return sum(random.choice([1,-1]) for _ in range(3))

num_ruined = 0
num_trials = 1000

for trial in range(num_trials):
    equity = 10
    for flip in range(1000):
        equity += flip_3_coins()
        if equity <= 0:
            num_ruined += 1
            break

print(num_ruined/num_trials)
```

The probability of ruin converges to 1 if you increase the number of flips (e.g. if you change this from 1000 to 10000 then the probability of ruin becomes ~0.95).