# Infinite dice roll probability

Tags: probability, markov-process, dice

The following is an interview question:

Two players A and B play a game rolling a fair die. If A rolls a 1, they immediately reroll, and if the reroll is less than 4 then A wins. Otherwise, B rolls. If B rolls a 6, they win, otherwise A rolls again, and so on. What is the probability A wins?

My approach: I have 4 states S (initial starting state), 1, 1-{1,2,3}, 6,  and this is my markov chain matrix

$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
    & \text{S} & \text{1} & \text{1-{1,2,3}} & \text{6} \\
    \hline
    \text{S} &  4/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/6 \\
    \text{1} & 33/36 & 0 & 3/36 & 0 \\
    \text{1-{1,2,3}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \text{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$

Using this I calculate probability of absorption to state 1-{1,2,3} and get 0.0769. Is this matrix the right set up? And is there a simpler way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: There are certainly simpler ways. It's pretty simple to see (or indeed to show) that the odds for A to eventually win $\frac{p}{1-p}$ (where $p$ is the desired probability) must be the same as the odds that A wins in round 1, *given someone wins in the first round*, where here a round begins every time we hit $S$. From there you can compute the odds  and then the probability that A wins overall in just a couple of lines.

Comment: You are using 'they', probably to be gender neutral, but in this context it is unclear whether it refers to a single player or both players.

Comment: Is this some homework question? Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for the suggestion, that seems much simpler. For the probability that A wins in round in 1 (call this event A), given someone wins in the first round (call this event B) I get: P(A|B) = (1/12)/(3/12) = 1/3. Which gives p=0.25. Is this correct?

Comment: How did you compute that 3/12 ?

Comment: Continuing the elegant insight by @glen_b, the chance that *someone* wins in the first round is $1/12$ (for A) plus $(1-1/12)(1/6)$ (for B), whence the chance $A$ wins given someone wins that round is $$\frac{1/12}{1/12 + (1-1/12)(1/6)}=\frac{6}{17}\approx 0.3529412.$$ In the notation of my answer this is, more generally, $$\frac{a}{a + (1-a)b}=\frac{a}{1-(1-a)(1-b)}.$$

Comment: The numerical answer (6/17) given by @whuber exactly matches the answer I got before I commented. It's simple enough that one can get it via mental calculation. Expanding on my first comment, note that the round by round  probabilities must be a geometrically decreasing multiple of those in the first round, and hence also the long-run probabilities will be in proportion to those in the first round. The ratio of their win probabilities (A-win:B-win) conveniently removes the need to play about with the "otherwise the game continues as before" part.

Comment: Cross post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856319/infinite-dice-roll-problem :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The matrix doesn't seem right, but it is difficult to see as the labels are not very clear. What is the transition from `1` to `1-{1,2,3}` and why is it 3/36?

Possibly it is easier to use:

$$\begin{array}{}M = & \begin{array}{c|cccc}
    & \text{A's turn} & \text{B's turn} & \text{A wins} & \text{B wins} \\
   \hline
    \text{A's turn} & 0 &  \frac{11}{12} & \frac{1}{12}  & 0  \\
    \text{B's turn } &  \frac{5}{6} &  0 &   0 &  \frac{1}{6} \\
   \text{A wins} &  0 &  0 &  1&  0  \\
   \text{B wins} &  0 &  0 &   0 &  1  \\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

You might want to consider the product of the matrix $M \cdot M$ which makes the state `A's turn` either return to the state `A's turn` or to one of the absorbing states.

[image: example of M²]

From this point there are different ways to solve it. (and also there are different ways to reach this point, the matrix formulation is not really neccesary)

- One may use a recursive formula formula like

  $$P(\text{A wins, given A starts in turn 1}) = \frac{55}{72} P(\text{A wins, given A starts in turn 3}) + \frac{1}{12}$$

  and solve it after substituting $P(\text{A wins, given A starts in turn 1})  = P(\text{A wins, given A starts in turn 3})$

  This reasoning also occurs in question like

  - [Amoeba Interview Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/)
  - [The Frog Problem (puzzle in YouTube video)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427165/)
  - [The Dead Drunk Man](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/623374/)
- Or plainly reason based on the odds for A and B $$P(\text{A wins}) = \frac{6/72}{6/72+11/72}$$
- Or compute the above reasoning more explicitly by expressing the total integral of 'fraction x time' that is spend in state $\text{A's turn}$

  $$P(\text{A wins}) = \frac{1}{12} \underbrace{ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{55}{72} \right)^k }_{= \frac{1}{1-\frac{55}{72}}}$$

That last case resembles the more genral matrix approach by Whuber, which I hope would score extra points. But it is difficult to say what the interviewers are looking for. If they had wanted a matrix approach, then they should have asked a question that asks for such approach (with less zero's in the matrix).

Comment: There is a connection between the several methods because the last one of them uses an identity for the infinite sum of a geometric series, whose proof is eventually similar to the recursive formula.

Answer (score 19):

Evidently $A$ has a $3/6 \times 1/6 = 1/12 = a$ chance of winning on their turn and $B$ has a $1/6 = b$ chance of winning.

From $A$'s perspective, their chance $p_A$ of winning this game is the sum of

1. The chance of winning immediately, equal to $a,$ and
2. The chance of not winning immediately ($1-a$) **times** the chance $B$ does not win on their turn ($1-b$) **times** the chance $p_A$ of winning, because at that point *the game restarts.*

Thus

> $$p_A = a + (1-a)(1-b)p_A\tag{*}$$

whose unique solution is easily found (which I leave to you to work out).

I you like to test things with simulations, here is one using `R`:

```R
play <- function(a, b) ifelse (runif(1) < a, 1, 1 - play(b, a))
mean(replicate(1e3, play(1/12, 1/6)))
```

> [1] 0.3458

This result differs from the correct value only by chance variation.

---

This answer disagrees with the value (0.0769) stated in the question, so **let's look at the Markov chain**.  There are four states:

- It is A's turn.
- It is B's turn.
- A has won.
- B has won.

The initial state is $(1,0,0,0),$ the final state is $(0,0,1,0),$ and the transition matrix (which reflects the definitions of $a$ and $b$ -- there's no computation needed) is

$$\mathbb P = \pmatrix{0&1-a&a&0\\ 1-b&0&0&b \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1}$$

You could compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors and turn the Markov Chain crank, but **the block matrix structure of $\mathbb P$ suggests a simpler way**.  Notice that

$$\mathbb P  = \pmatrix{\mathbb A&\mathbb B\\ 0 & \mathbb I}$$

with $\mathbb A = \pmatrix{0&1-a\\1-b&0}$ and $\mathbb B = \pmatrix{a&0\\0&b}$ for the top $2\times 2$ blocks.  When squaring any matrix in this form you find

$$\mathbb P^2 = \pmatrix{\mathbb A^2 & (\mathbb A + \mathbb I)\mathbb B\\ 0 & \mathbb I}.$$

**Iterating reveals a pattern in the upper right block:** within $\mathbb P^{2^n}$ it takes the form

$$(\mathbb A^{2^n-1} + \mathbb A^{2^n-2} + \cdots + \mathbb A + \mathbb I)\mathbb B$$

(easily established by induction).  This is a geometric series of matrices with limiting form

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P^{2^n} = (\mathbb I - \mathbb A)^{-1}\mathbb B.$$

You can read the chance of $A$ winning from the $(1,3)$ entry of $\mathbb P,$ equal to the $(1,1)$ entry of this limit,

$$(\mathbb I - \mathbb A)^{-1}\mathbb B = \pmatrix{1 & a-1\\b-1&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{a&0\\0&b} = \frac{1}{1 - (1-a)(1-b)}\pmatrix{a & *\\* & *},$$

which you can verify solves $(*)$ above.

Answer (score 1):

@Glen_b and @whuber have gave good answers, and I think the gist is the Bayesian formula.

---

Here is another method:

For a single round , the probabilities are:

```
P_A = 1/6 * 3/6 = 1/12
P_B = (1 - P_n_A ) * 1/6 = 11/12 * 1/6 = 11/72
P_Draw = 1 - P_n_A - P_n_B = 55/72
```

For round n, the probabilities are:

```
P_n_A = P_Draw ^ (n-1) * P_A
P_n_B = P_Draw ^ (n-1) * P_B
P_n_Draw = P_Draw ^ (n)
```

These are all geometric sequence, and the common ratio is:  `r= P_Draw`

The sum of the first n terms in a geometric sequence: `Sn = a1 * (1-r^n) / (1-r)`

So, the probability for A or B wins before round n is:

```
S_n_A = P_1_A + P_2_A + ... P_n_A = 1/12 * (1-r^n) / (1-r)
S_n_B = P_1_B + P_2_B + ... P_n_B = 11/72 * (1-r^n) / (1-r)
```

By the way, the probability for draw before round n is:  `r ^ (n)`

Because `r < 1`, so:

```
lim(n->∞)(S_n_A) = 1/12 * (1-0) / (1-r) = 1/12 / (1- 55/72) = 6/17
lim(n->∞)(S_n_B) = 11/72 * (1-0) / (1-r) =  11/72 / (1- 55/72) = 11/17
lim(n->∞)(draw_n) = lim(n->∞)(r ^ (n)) =  0
```

---

And we can get common formulas for this kind of games:

```
P_Draw_single = 1- P_A_single - P_B_single
P_Awin = P_A_single / (1 - P_Draw_single) 
P_Bwin = P_B_single / (1 - P_Draw_single)
```

Thus,

```
P_Awin = P_A_single / (P_A_single + P_B_single)
P_Bwin = P_B_single / (P_A_single + P_B_single)
```

---

For example, a more simplified game:
Two players A and B roll by turn, who rolls a 1 wins, and A rolls first.
So,

```
P_A_single = 1/6
P_B_single = 5/6 * 1/6 = 5/36
```

And,

```
P_Awin = P_A_single / (P_A_single + P_B_single) = 6/11
P_Bwin = P_B_single / (P_A_single + P_B_single) = 5/11
```

---

Further more, I think these common formulas can support more than 2 players.

```
P_Awin = P_A_single / (P_A_single + P_B_single + ......)
P_Bwin = P_B_single / (P_A_single + P_B_single + ......)
P_Cwin = P_C_single / (P_no_draw)
......
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't need matrices — this can be modeled with series. Let $P_W$ denote the probability $A$ wins on their roll, and $P_L$ denote the probability $A$ loses *but gets another chance to roll* (i.e., $B$ doesn't win on their roll). Then the probability $A$ wins overall, $P_O$, is the sum:

$$ P_O = P_W + (P_L)P_W + (P_L)^2P_W + \dots $$

This is a geometric series and using the [well-known formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) one can simplify this down to:

$$ P_O = \frac{P_W}{1 - P_L} $$

We can solve for $P_W$ and $P_L$ directly:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_W &= \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{12} \\
P_L &= \left[\frac{5}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\left(\frac{5}{6}\right) = \frac{55}{72}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, the overall chance $A$ wins is:

$$ P_O = \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{1 - \frac{55}{72}} = \frac{6}{17} $$

Answer (score 1):

Another graphical way to go about this is to use a familiar tree,

[image]

We see that the probability of $A$ winnning per game is $6/72$ and the probability of the game repeating is $50/72 + 5/72 = 55/72$. So the apriori probability for $A$ winning is

\begin{align}
\Pr({\rm A\; wins}) &= \frac 6{72} + \frac{55}{72} \cdot \frac 6{72} + \left(\frac{55}{72}\right)^2\cdot \frac 6{72}+\dots \\
&=\frac 6{72} \cdot \left( 1+ \frac{55}{72}  + \left(\frac{55}{72}\right)^2+\dots \right)\\
&= \frac 6{72}\cdot \frac {1}{1- 55/72} = \frac 6 {17}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry because I do not know Markow chains and such theorems because I am kind of new to high level math, but this probability question is something that I would like to answer and maybe, the methods above are just my method condensed but I do not understand the logic behind them and so I would like to show you the working of my method just in case it is different :

Let us break this up into the 3 cases possible for A to win :

$\text{Case 1 : A} \xrightarrow{\text{rolls a 1}}\text{A rolls again}\xrightarrow{\text{rolls < 4}} \text{A wins}$

$\text{Case 2 : A}\xrightarrow{\text{rolls a 1}}\text{A rolls again}\xrightarrow{\text{rolls > 3}}\text{B rolls}\xrightarrow{\text{does not roll a 6}}\text{A rolls again as if nothing ever happened (}``\text{a fresh start")}$

$\text{Case 3 : A}\xrightarrow{\text{does not roll a 1}}\text{B wolls}\xrightarrow{\text{does not roll a 6}}\text{A rolls again as if nothing ever happened (}``\text{a fresh start")}$

Let the probability of A winning the game eventually when nobody else has ever rolled the dice before is $P_a$

For case 1, we have a simple probability of $\frac{1}{6} \text{(to roll a 1)} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \text{(to roll < 4)} = \frac{1}{12}$

For case 2, A will first need to roll a 1 and then > 3 and then B will have to not roll a 6 and then probability of A winning eventually is just $P_a$ because A rolls again as if nothing ever happened and probability of A winning eventually before anybody ever rolled the dice is $P_a$ only.

So the probability comes out to be $\frac{1}{6} \text{(to roll a 1)} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \text{(to roll > 3)} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \text{(for B to not roll a 6)} \cdot P_a = \frac{5P_a}{72}$.

For case 3, A will have to not roll a 1 and then B will not have to roll a 6 and then again probability of A winning eventually is just $P_a$ because A rolls again as if nothing ever happened and probability of A winning eventually before anybody ever rolled the dice is $P_a$ only.

So the probability comes out to be $\frac{5}{6} \text{(to not roll a 1)} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \text{(for B to not roll a 6)} \cdot P_a = \frac{25P_a}{36}$.

As all of these are "cases" we have to add them all to find total probability of A winning eventually when nobody has ever rolled the dice before, but that is again just $P_a$

So $P_a = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{5P_a}{72} + \frac{25P_a}{36} = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{55P_a}{72}$

$\therefore P_a - \frac{55P_a}{72} = \frac{17P_a}{72} = \frac{1}{12} \implies P_a = \frac{6}{17}$

P.S. : The topmost answer is almost the same method (and exactly the same logic) but since I, being somewhat of a beginner in probability, found it confusing how they had reduced some steps in their answer, I decided to post this answer with much more explanation and understanding for people like me to better understand the solution.